# python celsius to fahrenheit conversion syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I wrote:

```
def celcius_to_fahrenheit:

fahr = (float(celcius) * 1.8) + 32
return fahr

celcius =input("Enter Degrees Celcius:")
print (celcius_to_fahrenheit)
```

and got the following error:

```
File ".\025 celcius-to-fahrenheit.py", line 1
def celcius_to_fahrenheit :
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in atom text reader

Comment: Add the brackets `()` (with the `celcius` argument inside) before `:` (in the 1st line). Also, indent your code (2nd and 3rd lines). Also check **celsius** spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is some little changes need in your code :

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius):
      fahr = (float(celsius) * 1.8) + 32
      return fahr

celsius =input("Enter Degrees Celsius:")
print (celsius_to_fahrenheit(celsius))
```

in python always remember about your indentation and function calling and defining should be like this

Comment: You kept the typo of `celcius`.  Maybe fix that as well.